# Change list of Eithers to two value lists in scala

Tags: scala, either

How can I change list of Eithers into two list of value Right and Left. When I use `partition` it returns two lists of Either's not values. What is the simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`foldLeft` allows you to easily write your own method:

```
def separateEithers[T, U](list: List[Either[T, U]]) = {
  val (ls, rs) = list.foldLeft(List[T](), List[U]()) {
    case ((ls, rs), Left(x)) => (x :: ls, rs)
    case ((ls, rs), Right(x)) => (ls, x :: rs)
  }
  (ls.reverse, rs.reverse)
}
```

Comment: I'm nitpicking you, but it doesn't look like a *simplest* way :-)

Comment: True, your solution is simpler :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to `map` the two resulting lists after partitioning.

```
val origin: List[Either[A, B]] = ???
val (lefts, rights) = origin.partition(_.isInstanceOf[Left[_]])
val leftValues = lefts.map(_.asInstanceOf[Left[A]].a)
val rightValues = rights.map(_.asInstanceOf[Right[B]].b)
```

If you are not happy with the casts and isInstanceOf's, you can also do it in two passes:

```
val leftValues = origin collect {
  case Left(a) => a
}
val rightValues = origin collect {
  case Right(b) => b
}
```

And if you are not happy with the two passes, you'll have to do it "by hand":

```
def myPartition[A, B](origin: List[Either[A, B]]): (List[A], List[B]) = {
  val leftBuilder = List.newBuilder[A]
  val rightBuilder = List.newBuilder[B]
  origin foreach {
    case Left(a)  => leftBuilder += a
    case Right(b) => rightBuilder += b
  }
  (leftBuilder.result(), rightBuilder.result())
}
```

Finally, if you don't like mutable state, you can do so:

```
def myPartition[A, B](origin: List[Either[A, B]]): (List[A], List[B]) = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(xs: List[Either[A, B]], accLeft: List[A],
      accRight: List[B]): (List[A], List[B]) = {
    xs match {
      case Nil            => (accLeft.reverse, accRight.reverse)
      case Left(a) :: xr  => loop(xr, a :: accLeft, accRight)
      case Right(b) :: xr => loop(xr, accLeft, b :: accRight)
    }
  }
  loop(origin, Nil, Nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If making two passes through the list is okay for you, you can use collect:

```
type E = Either[String, Int]
val xs: List[E] = List(Left("foo"), Right(1), Left("bar"), Right(2))
val rights = xs.collect { case Right(x) => x}
// rights: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

val lefts = xs.collect { case Left(x) => x}
// lefts: List[String] = List(foo, bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using for comprehensions, like this,

```
for ( Left(v) <- xs ) yield v
```

and

```
for ( Right(v) <- xs ) yield v
```